# How do I use Nokogiri XML Builder with a field that is the word "text"?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I think "text" must be a special form because when I use xml.text "hello" the  tag doesn't appear in the xml doc.  Whatever follows that tag is simply listed without a .  I tried to use send.(:"text", "hello") but that doesn't work either.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it using the "special tags" in Nokogiri.

Answer (score 4):

Which means you need to put an underscore after the tag name.

Just to clarify with an example for anyone else who might be searching for this (such as I was):

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.questions {
    xml.question {
      xml.text_ "What is your name?"
    }
    xml.question {
      xml.text_ "What is your favourite colour?"
    }
  }
end
```